# What is a shorthand way for checking that multiple variables are ALL equal to the same value in an IF statement? (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a shorthand way of writing the code below?

```
if (($tstat=='no_prices')&&($l1stat=='no_prices')&&($l2stat=='no_prices')&&($l3stat=='no_prices'))
{                                   
    //do something
}
```

I tried using the below code,but it did something when one of the variables was not equal to 'no_prices'.

```
if (($tstat && $l1stat && $l2stat && $l3stat)=='no_prices')
{
    //do something
}
```

To check that the strings weren't causing problems I tried substituting 0 for 'no_prices' and 1 for other values, but the result was the same.

Comment: To ensure that N items are equal, it is necessary to do at most N-1 comparisons. Your original code is probably most efficient and most indicative of the intent.
array_unique will make Perm(N-1) comparisons, i.e. comparing each element of the given array to every other element. This is horribly wasteful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) is several times faster than [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```php
function all_equal($arr, $value) {
  return array_keys(array_flip($arr)) == array($value);
}

$arr = array($tstat, $l1stat, $l2stat, $l3stat);

echo all_equal($arr, 'no_prices');
```

A quick profile for the answers given thus far, for 1000 iterations on array length 1000:

```php
  array_flip: 0.07321620 seconds
array_unique: 0.32569408 seconds
     foreach: 0.15136194 seconds
array_filter: 0.41404295 seconds
```

The code used to profile is here: http://codepad.org/szgNfWHe

**Note**: As @cypherabe [rightly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141374/#comment33618070_22142889), `array_flip` does not overtake `array_unique` until the array has at least 5 elements, and does not overtake `foreach` until the array has at least 10 elements.

Comment: great idea, very good thinking. although I have one small nitpick: it doesn't look too good with small arrays: i tested with just 3 items and 10000 iterations: array_flip: 0.13334584 seconds
array_unique: 0.10228825 seconds foreach: 0.07458353 seconds array_filter: 0.25514889 seconds longform: 0.04010510 seconds // (longform: if statement with 3 variables tested) codepad: http://codepad.org/5ULGtImN it gives slightly different times, strangely

Answer (score 9):

Unless I'm mistaken, there's no native way of doing this. If this is something that you have to check for often, try using a custom function for it, e.g.:

```
function allEquals($chkstr, $vals) {
    if (!is_array($vals)) { die('allEquals() $vals not an array'); }
    foreach ($vals AS $v) {
        if ($chkstr != $v) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution is the most efficient one suggested, without even considering the short-circuiting behavior.

Comment: This is the best option IMO, because its by far the most readable solution when you review your code in 12 months time. Shorthand is not everything.

Answer (score 7):

My first idea would go into PHP's Array API:

```
// $tstadt, $l1stat, … are all "no_prices"
$isAllNoPrice = array_unique(array($tstat, $l1stat, …)) == array("no_prices"));
if ($isAllNoPrice) {
    // …

}
```

**Documentation is mandatory otherwise nobody (including yourself) will understand the code.**

If efficiency might be a concern others pointed out that `array_unique()` seems to be slow. Using the keys of the hash table would be a next approach:

```
// $tstadt, $l1stat, … are all "no_prices"
$varsMap = array(
    $tstat  => null,
    $l1stat => null,
    // …
);
if (array_keys($varsMap) == array("no_prices")) {
    // …

}
```

But now the wall of code is growing. PHP offers one operator which *nearly* does what you want and is chainable: [`&`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
$v1 = "no_prices";
$v2 = "no_prices";
$v3 = "no_prices";

var_dump(($v1 & $v2 & $v3) == "no_prices"); // bool(true)

$v3 = "prices";
var_dump(($v1 & $v2 & $v3) == "no_prices"); // bool(false)
```

I said it *nearly* does what you want: There are cases in which you will have false positives:

```
$v1 = 1;
$v2 = 1;
$v3 = 3;

var_dump(($v1 & $v2 & $v3) == 1); // bool(true)
```

For Strings it seems to cut the bitmask to the shortest string:

```
$v1 = "abcd";
$v2 = "ab";
$v3 = "abc";

var_dump($v1 & $v2 & $v3); // "ab"
var_dump(($v1 & $v2 & $v3) == "ab"); // bool(true)
```

So I don't recommend this as a general purpose solution. <del>Only if you know (=unit tested) that your values are in a set where no combination never results to a false positive (e.g. {"dog", "cat", "horse"}) you might consider this solution.</del> I gave it a second thought and must say don't use that at all. Imagine how your colleagues will love you for searching a bug introduced by that method.

Comment: first () will return true/false and you are comparing true/false to $l1stat

Comment: True, I changed my answer.

Comment: It should be said that `array_unique` is a relatively slow function that should be avoided, if not necessary. And it almost never is.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can do:

```
if (count(array_unique($tstat, $l1stat, $l2stat, $l3stat)) == 1 //Check if all share the same value (i.e., number of unique values is 1
&& $tstat == 'no_prices')) //If everything is the same and $stat == 'no_prices', then everything is 'no_prices'
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$tstat = $l1stat = $l2stat = $l3stat = 'no_prices';
$testVars = array($tstat,$l1stat,$l2stat,$l3stat);

if(count(array_filter($testVars, function($x) { return $x === 'no_prices'; })) == count($testVars))
{
        print("Correct");
}
```

Use array_filter with a anonymous callback, and check if its length is greater is equal to original array i.e. all conditions passed,

or if length is greater than zero i.e. any one condition passed

Answer (score 2):

No, this code won't work:

```
if (($tstat&&$l1stat&&$l2stat&&$l3stat)=='no_prices')
{
    //do something
}
```

Why? Because condition in parentheses, will check result itself - You are comparing boolean to string. So in pseudo-code, thats what your code looks like:

```
if ( ($tstat is true, $l1stat is true, $l2stat is true, $l3stat is true) == 'no_prices' )
     ^                         whole thing returns true                ^    ^   true  ^
```

If you wan't to achieve this, you can use `count()` and `array_unique()`:

```
if ($tstat == 'no_prices' && count(array_unique(array($tstat, $l1stat, $l2stat, $l3stat))) == 1)
```

Comment: Your solution will return true when ONE of the variables has the expected value. The OP needs a solution to fire true when ALL variables have the expected value.

Comment: Your `in_array` simply checks that 'no_prices' exists in *any* of the parameters.

Comment: in_array will not be work for `&&` it will work only for `||`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$arr = array($tstat,$l1stat,...); //make an array
$arr =array_unique($arr);//unique this array

if(count($arr) == 1 && $arr[0] = 'no_prices'){ // check if only one array element have with same value
    echo "got it";
}
```

[demo example](https://eval.in/108039)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no". There's no shorthand to the given condition that will make your code more readable, which should be your top priority. You can improve it though:

```
define('MYAPP_NO_PRICES', 'no_prices');

if ($tstat === MYAPP_NO_PRICES
        && $l1stat === MYAPP_NO_PRICES
        && $l2stat === MYAPP_NO_PRICES
        && $l3stat === MYAPP_NO_PRICES) {                                 
    // do something
}
```

Having all these vars to check individually is a code smell; you might want to rethink this design so you never have to do this.